# Making geospatial queries using Express/Node.JS/MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm brand new to Express/Node.JS/MongoDB and trying to write a simple lookup tool for making geospatial queries.

I'm using a hosted MongoDB (MongoLab), have built the indexes, and when I run the geospatial search query within their online command tool I'm able get a return.

Here is a copy of the code inside the routes directory, the file is named query.js:

```js
var Db = require('mongodb').Db;
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/query', function(req, res) {
    if (req.params) {
        console.log(req.params);
        var lon = parseFloat(req.query.longitude);
        var lat = parseFloat(req.query.latitude);

        Db.connect(process.env.MONGOLAB_URI, function (err, db) {
            if (err) return console.dir(err);

            db.collection('bfe_lines')
                .find({
                    "near": [lon, lat],
                    "num": 1,
                    "spherical": true
                }).toArray(function (err, docs) {
                if (err) {
                    return console.dir(err)
                }
                else {
                    console.log(docs)
                }
            })
        })
    }
    else {
        res.send("no joy");
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

The response I'm getting back on the command line looks like this:

```
GET / 304 14.003 ms - -
{}
GET /query?latitude=40.49973185600004&longitude=-88.99786877199995 500 5.683 ms - 534
```

Thank you to anyone that can help me.

Comment: I think instead of using `var Db = require('mongodb').Db;`, it should be `var Db = require('mongodb').MongoClient;`